# Will combined index work for queries on only one column?

Tags: sql, postgresql, indexing

I am using PostgreSQL. I am not sure that if I have a combined index, say on column `A` and `B`, when I query only of `B`, will the index be used?

Answer (score 1):

No, it will not.  The index would be used for a condition only on `A`, but not only on `B`.  Such an index would be used for the following (example) cases:

```
where A = 1
where A < 10
where A = 1 and B = 2
where A = 1 and B < 10
```

It would not be used for:

```
where B = 2
where B < 10
```

For the following, it would be used only for the `A` condition, if at all:

```
where A < 10 and B = 2
where A < 10 and B < 10
```

I happen to think that the MySQL [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/multiple-column-indexes.html) does a good job of explaining composite indexes.  (Ignore the details on hash indexes which are specific to the MySQL implementation.)

Answer (score 1):

Both answers so far are *incorrect*. The index *can* be used in any case.

The sequence of columns in a [multicolumn index](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/indexes-multicolumn.html) is relevant. In particular in a **B-tree** index (which is the default). GiN or GiST indexes behave differently.

Queries on the *leading* column(s) are perfectly efficient. The only downside of additional columns: the growing size of the index.

Postgres *can* even use multicolumn indexes for query conditions ignoring the leading column. That use case is *far less efficient*, though.

We have discussed this in great detail on dba.SE:
[Working of indexes in PostgreSQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/6115/working-of-indexes-in-postgresql/7484#7484)
[Is a composite index also good for queries on the first field?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/27481/is-a-composite-index-also-good-for-queries-on-the-first-field/27493#27493)

Answer (score 0):

Answer is No, they explains it here.

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/indexes-bitmap-scans.html